# Read multiple line from txt | JAVA

Tags: java, file, io

How to read multiple line in a .txt file ?

```
    //WRITE A ELEMENT OF ARRAY TO TXT
public static void write_array_element(Persona value,String path) throws IOException{
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(path),true));
    out.write(value.name);
    out.newLine();
    out.write(value.surname);
    out.newLine();
    out.write(value.d);
    out.newLine();
    out.write(value.m);
    out.newLine();
    out.write(value.y);
    out.newLine();
    out.newLine();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

This function write five line in a .txt at Append Write Mode, in other function I read the five line for set up element, but not read all lines but only first five line and leave out other lines.

```
//READ ELEMENT OF ARRAY FROM TXT
public static Persona read_from_txt(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
    String name = in.readLine();
    String surname = in.readLine();
    String d = in.readLine();
    String m = in.readLine();
    String y = in.readLine();
    Persona tmp = new Persona(name,surname,d,m,y);
    return tmp;
}
```

With in.readLine(); I can read the five's element line , but when I try to set up all elements from txt to array, I get only first element of txt.
Help me ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to read beyond the first five lines?

Comment: @JoeC I have to save a list in txt , the code must be able to read a txt and create an array, txt contains information about person in this mode : 1 line) name; 2  line) surname; 3 line) day for birth; 4 line) month for birth; 5 line) year for birth; 6 line ) " " blank line for separate element. After the sixth line start a new element with name,surname etc..

Comment: The problem is that you think your program should read more than five lines.  I cannot help you unless you can tell me why you think this.  (I'm not going to rewrite it for you, and nor is anyone else on this site, but I'm happy to clear up any misunderstandings you have about your code if I know what they are.)

Comment: @JoeC I'm not looking for anyone who rewrites it for me, I think I need a set cycle
to EOF, but how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a set cycle to EOF, but how ?

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        //...
}
```

Also, make a method in your Persona class which will return personas values ready for your txt. So you can write persona info at once.
example:

```
String printPersona(){ return name + "\n" + surname + "\n" + ... }
```

(or you can name it toString())

Comment: I try with do while for read name also, but It works ! I have to fix a few lines of code to avoid the last null string..  Thanks !